# Bootstrap Grid Re-sizing content to new location on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to boot strap so I may be thinking of this objective in an incorrect way, so I would appreciate any advice as well as a solution.

Say for example I have a left column

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">Some Data 0</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">Some Data 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">Some Data 2</div>
</div>
```

When the screen matches the XS I would like "Some Data 0" to be wrapped in a modal component.  So that "Some Data 0" is now hidden in a modal window and a button is in it's place that when clicked will display the modal window with the content "Some Data 0"

How is this accomplished in Bootstrap.  Is the only way to duplicate "Some Data 0" and just show and hide based on the screen breakpoints?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well you can achieve it in this way i guess :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 hidden-xs">Some Data 0</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-md visible-xs"> Handle your modal with Some Data 0 in this div</div>

    <div class="col-md-3 hidden-xs">Some Data 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-md visible-xs">Handle your modal with Some Data 1 in this div</div>

    <div class="col-md-3 hidden-xs">Some Data 2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-md visible-xs">Handle your modal with Some Data 2 in this div</div>
</div>
```

Key feature here is to use `hidden-{}` and `visible-{}` classes.

Comment: I though about that, but then I have to duplicate "Some Data 0" twice on the page.  Is there a way to accomplish this without having to duplicate the data?